# java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException being thrown from methods running in threads

Tags: java

I am trying to create basic producer/consuner class using:

```
public class ProducerConsumer {
    private final static int MAX_SIZE = 100;
    private Queue<String> data = new PriorityQueue<>();
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition bufferFull = lock.newCondition();
    private Condition bufferEmpty = lock.newCondition();

    public void produce(){
        while(true) {
            try {
                lock.lock();
                while (data.size() >= MAX_SIZE) {
                    bufferFull.await();
                }
                addData();
                bufferEmpty.notifyAll();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("error produce");
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
    public void consume(){
        while(true) {
            try {
                lock.lock();
                while (data.isEmpty()) {
                    bufferEmpty.await();
                }
                String value = data.poll();
                System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " processing value " + value);
                bufferFull.notifyAll();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("error consume");
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    private void addData(){
        IntStream.range(0,10).forEach( i ->
                data.add(new Date().toString())
        );
    }

    public void start(int consumerNumber){
        IntStream.range(0,consumerNumber)
                .mapToObj(i -> new Thread(this::consume))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .forEach(Thread::start);

        Thread t = new Thread(this::produce);
        t.start();
    }

}
```

However it keeps throwing error: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException. My question is, why does it throw this error? method of this intance are running in threads, so they should own condition lock thus i dont understand meaning behind this error.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Did you [read the Javadoc of the exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html)? "Thrown to indicate that a thread has attempted to wait on an object's monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor."

Comment: yes i did but im quite not sure what it means, own as thread locked the condition/lock?

Comment: @AndyTurner according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html my way of locking should be correct, yet exception is thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bufferEmpty.notifyAll()` is the wrong method to call. That method requires you hold the monitor on the "bufferEmpty" object itself, which is unrelated to the `lock` instance you're using.

The right method to call is

```
bufferEmpty.signalAll();
```